# how to i add two columns in Awk Ubuntu that are strings(which are integers)?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I am trying add two columns in a text file that are seperated by tabs. I need to use awk to do this. They are two integers that i need to add.

Comment: What's wrong with `awk -e '{ print($1 + $2)'`? Did you actually try?

Comment: @Staven: What's wrong with it is that you forgot the closing curly bracket. :P I don't think you need `-e`, but what does it do? I don't find it in my gawk man pages.

Comment: @flesk: Well, then you didn't search very well. :P `-e program-text`, `--source program text`: Use program-text as AWK program source code. You're right in saying it isn't needed, though.

Comment: @Staven `echo flesk | awk -e '{print}'` just prints usage info on my version (GNU Awk 3.1.3). `-W source` and `--source` works though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work

```
awk '{ print $1+$2; }' file.txt
```